# How to attach event listeners to class instance?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a simple date picker plugin. I need to add event listeners to the month names, so that when a user clicks a month, it will set it as the selected month. There can be a few date pickers on the screen so I need the listener to match the months of the clicked instance and not change the others.

Before I changed the code to class, I had a working code for a single instance of the date picker:

```
attachEvents: function() {
    let monthElements = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker .month');
    for (i = 0; i < monthElements.length; i++) {
        monthElements[i].addEventListener("click", setDate, false);
    }
}
```

But now I have a few issues: since I need it to work for few instances, I assume I can't use this selector because it would choose any other month element in the Dom, even from another instance.

How can I set the event listeners only to month elements by the same instance, so that I will listen to events on the correct date picker?

Comment: You can call querySelectorAll on any element you like, to only search in the partial tree below that.

Comment: So will it be a good idea to save the date picker element as a class field and set it perhaps in the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make this change only to the element that you have selected, you have to choose your `monthElements` based on your click.

If your `.datepicker .month` is inside your element that you have clicked, you can modify your selector as below

```
let monthElements = event.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('.datepicker .month');
```

And the code will be like

```
attachEvents: function(event) {
    let monthElements = event.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('.datepicker .month');
    for (i = 0; i < monthElements.length; i++) {
        monthElements[i].addEventListener("click", setDate, false);
    }
}
```

Please note, the only hing that you have to do is to select the `monthElements` correctly. If your DOM hierarchy is not like what I explained, please update your query selector accordingly.

Comment: I think I get the idea. But in your example I don't think it would work because the function itself is meant to set the event listeners. It doesn't exist when it comes to this function yet. So what I can do is to save the date picker element in the class constructor and use it instead of `event.currentTarget`?